# Upload file, not such file or directory - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, filepath

I have this in the index (pieces_path)

```
<%= form_tag (upload_pieces_path) do%>
  <%= file_field_tag 'data' %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

And this in the pieces controller

```
def upload
  file_data = params[:data]
  File.read(file_data, 'r') do |file|

     file.each do |line|
       ## .... ##
     end

   end
   redirect_to pieces_path
end
```

Finally the routes

```
match '/upload_pieces', to: 'pieces#upload', via: 'post'
```

The idea is to read a file in the view, then do something with him ,not save it in the database, then return to the previous page.

But when i test it i receive a "No such file or directory" error when i upload a file.

Any ideas?, what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `multipart` option to `form_tag`:

```
<%= form_tag(upload_pieces_path, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'data' %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you markets
You just skip the `file = file_data.read` instead of the `File.read(file_data, 'r')` in the controller but you help me a lot

Comment: You're welcome. I think `Rack` parses the file using [this class](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Multipart/UploadedFile.html), so should also be valid: `File.read(file_data.original_filename, 'r')`.